# How to get HwndSourceHook from HwndSource

Tags: wpf, hook

in wpf, i can addHook as below'

```
HwndSource src = HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
if (src != null) src.AddHook(WndProc);
```

but, how can i get WndProc from the HwndSource? or can i get get the flag the WndProc is add?

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to get `WndProc` from anywhere. The parameter to `AddHook` is a delegate of type [`HwndSourceHook`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndsourcehook.aspx) that you will supply yourself; after all, this is why you bother to call `AddHook` in the first place.

Comment: thx for your help.but why i want to check the HwndSourceHook is , second AddHook's WndProc will override first AddHook's WndProc.